# Push button with auto off

Tags: transistors, timer, button

How to make push button switch with auto off after about 5 seconds.
Output circuit is high (active) for max 5 seconds when I keep pressing push button.
Output will be low after this time or  when I release push button.
To reactivate, I have to release push button and press again.
I think that it's using a capacitor charging with some transistors. But how to make it work?

Comment: Monostable circuit (555 or transistor version).

Comment: Btw, if you choose a transistor version a good approach is to trigger it with RC differentiator connected to signal diode to transistor base to avoid holding output high while pressing button too long.

Comment: Yes I looking for transistor version. And as simple as possible. Can you show your schematic in answer?

Comment: It can be done with transistors **BUT** it is much easier to use eg a single IC such as a 74xx14 / CD 40206 / .... hex Schmitt trigger. I can provide a circuit IF it would be of interest.

Comment: The tricky part is to have the count starting when you *push* the button instead of when you *release* it. A normal monostable would lengthen the pulse but this can also shorten it. The trick is AC coupling the button so it only gives a pulse. In IC form the 4047 is the historical implementation. Doing it with transistor is feasible but timing tend to be inconsistent unless you use a somewhat complex circuit (the problem historically solved by the 555 which is sold as a 'precision' timer)

Comment: @Russell McMahon. Yes the schematic is all I need. But I prefer to use transistors cz it easier to found in my workshop than a specific ic. I looking for simplest or tricky circuit.

Comment: @Lorenzo Marcantonio. Precision is not critical here, since I need second value, not microsecond or below. So I think it can be done with a pot and/or change capacitor value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic idea (functional), but it may need to be tuned like R5/C2 time constant, switching spikes on transistors (add little capacity to slow it), width of trigger pulse, etc...

Edit: You get better result with R3,R8=1k , and C2= 68uF (almost exact 5sec)

[image]

[image]

(green is button press, blue is output voltage)

Comment: The timing looks good, although fall time not so quick. But seem that at the next button pressing we have to wait button open for a moment to let C2 fully charged before pressing again. Without C2 fully charged, on time will reduced. CMIW.

Comment: You are right, all you can to speed up charging is to change R3 and R8 to 1k as I mention in Edit or use smaller C2.

Comment: @reverse diode across R6 should improve retrigger time.